# Cannot cast datatype in Hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am having trouble casting a field from string to timestamp in hive after running date formats on it. The example of what I am trying to do is as follows:

```
select cast(date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(my_date ,'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a'), 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a') as timestamp) my_date  
from sample_schema.sample_table
```

The natural datatype this select statement results in is string and I need to be able to cast this to timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `my_date` is in `"MM/dd/yyyy"` format.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(my_date, "MM/dd/yyyy"),"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```